# How to configure odata web api route for method that always returns single entity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'd like to configure a route that always returns a single entity.

The controller looks like:

`class StatsController: ODataController {
    public Stats Get() { 
       return new Stats();
    }
}`

The url to access it should be: GET ~/service-prefix/stats

All the options I've seen involve having to return IQueryable, or when returning a single entity, passing in a key in a form of ~/service-prefix/EntitySet(1)

Is there a way to achieve the above without having to return an IQueriable?

Comment: Per the OData protocol, the path segment after service-prefix is mostly an entity set, which means a collection of entities will be returned. May I know that why you want only ONE entity instead of a collection by requesting such a URL?

Comment: @tanjinfu Conceptually the endpoint will always return a single object. The object represent a current state of the application, which is never a collection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a single object without needing to have an entityset, odata v4 introduces the concept of singletons.

[From OData v4 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-os-part3-csdl.html#_Toc372793988):

> A singleton allows addressing a single entity directly from the entity container without having to know its key, and without requiring an entity set.

More info:

- [Use Singleton to define your special entity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/05/use-singleton-to-define-your-special-entity.aspx)
- [ODataLib for OData v4: Singletons and Containment](http://odata.jenspinney.com/2014/02/odatalib-odata-v4/)

Comment: hmm..how is this `Singleton` related to your question?

Comment: @KiranChalla, the concept of singleton in the context of the OData api is exactly what I needed: a single entity that service provides, which is never in the collection, and which can be addressed without having to provide an index

Answer (score 0):

By default any action of the following forms should be reachable for your scenario:

Example:

`public Stat Get([FromODataUri] int key) { }`

or

`public Stat Get#your-entity-name#([FromODataUri] int key) { }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe Singleton could meet your requirement, but it is not implemented in WebApi. Fortunately, there is another option: unbound function. Just follow this sample: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/.

There is a method in ProductsController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("GetSalesTaxRate(state={state})")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSalesTaxRate([FromODataUri] string state)
    {
        return Ok(GetRate(state));
    }
```

It is requested through this URL: ~/service-prefix/GetSalesTaxReate(state='WA') and is very close to your scenario. The only thing you need to do is to remove the parameter of the function:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("GetStats()")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStats()
    {
        return Ok(new Stats());
    }
```

Now you can request ~/sevice-prefix/GetStats().